# Update URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string:

`http://www.website.com?a=111&b=2222&d=3333`

How can I take this string and update the `b` parameter value with `4444`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.replace(/b=([^&]*)/, "b=4444")`

Comment: This will replace "b=2222" with 4444 - which is not what he wants.

Comment: This is wrong. It will replace also the `b=` part so the replacement should be `b=4444`.

Comment: Ahh, of course. I misread my book. Corrected. (No matter how many times I use them, I never quite get the hang of regular expressions.)

Comment: Thanks but when I run this through JSHint I get the error "Insecure '^'" - how can I fix this?

Comment: I didn't see that error. Perhaps it wants you to replace the & with \& ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = 'http://www.website.com?a=111&b=2222&d=3333';
str.replace(/([&\?]b=\d+/,"$1b=4444")
```

Comment: what about if it is the first variable in the querystring?

Answer (score -1):

```
var myString = "http://www.website.com?a=111&b=2222&d=3333".replace("b=2222","b=4444")
```

Comment: I thought the first argument of ".replace" had to be a regex.

Comment: Nope. It can be a regular string.